# Anchor tags creating no route matching error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On the long home page of my Rails app, I have a link near the top and an anchor near the bottom, which takes users to a list of the site's imaginary top contributors.

Link

```
<a href="#link" class="bb-url">Top Contributors</a>
```

Anchor

```
<a name="link"></a>
```

The problem with this is that, once clicked, it creates a url  `http://localhost:3000/#link` and then, if the user refreshes the page, that link becomes  `http://localhost:3000/link` and then I get a `No route matches [GET] "/link"` error if the user refreshes the page again. There's not only the problem with functionality (site breaking), it's kind of ugly to have the #link but that might be avoidable.

Interested in what Rails offers, I tried to create the same with Rails `:anchor` option

```
<%= link_to('Top Contributors', root_path, :anchor => '#link') %>
```

However, this didn't work in several different ways. First, it triggered a total page refresh and then it didn't even take me to the anchor! Obviously I'm using the Rails anchor incorrectly, but the html version has its own problems (in the way I'm using it).

Can you explain the best way to do this?

```
**Update:**
```

The syntax is figured out to create the anchor but a problem remains

```
<%= link_to('Top Contributors', root_path(:anchor => 'topcontributors')) %>
<a name="topcontributors"></a>
```

If I click the link, it creates the url with a hashtag `localhost:3000/#topcontributors` If I then refresh the page, the hashtag disappears `localhost:3000/topcontributors` leaving a route that doesnt' exist, creating an error. It's the same problem in chrome, firefox, safari.

Answer (score 4):

The actual syntax is as follows:

```
<%= link_to('Top Contributors', root_path(:anchor => 'link')) %>
```

Source: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Comment: Thanks but that's not working. It's not moving the page and it's creating a url `http://localhost:3000/#%23link`

Comment: There was an extra `#` character. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks, it works, but there's still the same problem (described in the OP) as with the hardcoded anchor. It creates a url `localhost:3000/#link` which, if there's a page refresh, becomes `localhost:3000/link`, which, if there's a page refresh, creates a no matching route error (for `localhost:3000/link`). Do you know how to avoid that?

Comment: That's a very odd behavior. I'm trying to reproduce it here.

Comment: I ran the same code, making a link to the root route with an anchor just the same way. But on page refresh the URL remains the same. Did you test it in another browser? I really can't think of a reason why it would change the URL like that.

Comment: It's doing it in three browsers (safari, firefox, chrome).

Comment: I had to create an awkward hack  `get "link" => "home#index"` to avoid that routing error if user refreshes page more than once after pressing anchor.

Comment: Yeah, I never seen that before. Let's see if someone else can enlighten us on that...